# Gulp server issue while trying to run

Tags: ubuntu, gulp, gulp-karma

I seem to get an odd error when trying to get a project run, its seems to work fine in mac, but i am not able to get it run in Windows/ubuntu

```
/home/nicholas/Desktop/Workspace/projectx/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:47
            throw new Error('Task '+name+' can\'t support dependencies that is not an a
                  ^
Error: Task connect can't support dependencies that is not an array of strings
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.add (/home/nicholas/Desktop/Workspace/projectx/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:47:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nicholas/Desktop/Workspace/projectx/Gulpfile.js:66:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:62:18)
    at Liftoff.launch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:144:6)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to set up a task, called `'connect'`, and you have the second argument set to something other than an array of strings or a function.

ie, you have this:

```
gulp.task('connect', 'some-other-task', function() {
    //...
});
```

But, it can only be this:

```
gulp.task('connect', ['some-other-task'], function() {
    //...
});
```

The reason for the difference is most likely that `gulp` (or, rather, `Orchestrator`) was updated on the Windows machine, but not on the Mac.  If you run `npm list` from within the directory on both machines, it should show you the currently installed versions.  If you run `npm up` on the Mac, it most likely will have the same error as the other machine.

Comment: what if the second argument is a gulp task imported from another file?